# Dropdown não mostra background

Tags: html, css

Olá alguém pode me ajudar com um problema que venho enfrentando a uns 2 dias, meu dropdown não mostra background sem o (overflow-y:auto;) porém se eu colocar o overflow o submenu fica junto e eu quero ele separado assim. Alguém disposto a me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem o seu problema com o overflow mas pelo que vi o real problema é fazer aparecer o background do seu submenu. isso provavelmente ocorre por causa da estilização usada em `.down-content` veja o exemplo a seguir retirado de https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/xhiJH no qual não é necessário overflow.

```css
nav {
 margin: 50px 0;
 background-color: #E64A19;
}

nav ul {
 padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}
 
nav ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 background-color: #E64A19;
}

nav a {
 display:block;
 padding:0 10px; 
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height: 60px;
 text-decoration:none;
}

nav a:hover { 
 background-color: #000000; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
 top: 60px; /* the height of the main nav */
}
 
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:inherit;
}
 
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
 width:170px;
 float:none;
 display:list-item;
 position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers */
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top:-60px; 
 left:170px;
}

 
/* Change this in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
             <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                        <!-- Third Tier Drop Down -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Things</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Other Stuff</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

fonte: